# Python test-based class relationship analysis?

Tags: python, tdd, uml, reverse-engineering

Is a tool that, given I have 100% source code test coverage, would run the tests, analyse the relationships between the classes there and give me an UML diagram as an output (or some other form I could possibly convert to UML)?

Comment: What does test coverage have to do with UML diagrams?

Comment: It'd be hard to catch all dependencies on syntax basis only, thus the question.

Comment: In fact, if you want to detect the code dependences, the *first* thing you need is (to parse the) "syntax", then you need name resolution, and perhaps flow analysis.   But you can't catch any dependencies with test coverage.  All it tells you is that some code got executed, but not what that executed code depends upon.

Comment: Python is an interpreted language. You can pass references in a really convoluted manner, impossible to trace using a casual syntax parser. Functions like eval() and lambda expressions don't make it easier for them either. That's why I'm asking for a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: I understand Python is hard to analyze statically.  You have implied that somehow test coverage can act as a substitute.  I'm trying to understand how you think that might be possible; what is the information content of test coverage that would give you class relationships?

Comment: One *could* consider instrumenting Python code to collect arbitrary relationships at runtime, e.g., "class A was created using class B as a parent".  That might produce the information you want.  That instrumentation isn't test coverage, though.

Comment: When your code is test covered, a theoretical code analyzer would run the tests in a debugging environment, watching for the interactions between objects. That's what I meant.

Comment: To "watch[ing] for interactions" your "theoretical code analyzer" is essentially the relationship instrumentation I proposed.   You are suggesting that with 100% code coverage, such instrumentation would collect/have all the useful facts, thus giving you the basis for a good UML model?   Now I guess I understand; but its not quite right; you need to "cover" all possible *dataflows* to know about all possible interactions, and classic test coverage tools don't do that.  But you are missing that "theoretical instrumentation".  And you are asking for an existing tool, not a theoretical one.

Comment: If you are interested in *how* one might instrument the code, I can provide an answer.